# Need to resolve Ipopt BinPacking use case using JuMP

Tags: jupyter-notebook, linear-programming, julia-jump, ipopt

I want to solve binpacking problem using Ipopt with JuMP which is a linear programming. Can someone help me with the code

Comment: BinPacking needs a MIP solver. Ipopt however, is for continuous nonlinear problems. So this is a strange request.

Answer (score 0):

I already replied to your previous question:
[Constraints of type MathOptInterface.VariableIndex-in-MathOptInterface.ZeroOne are not supported by the solver. When using Ipopt solver in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70389253/constraints-of-type-mathoptinterface-variableindex-in-mathoptinterface-zeroone-a)

The JuMP community forum is a more appropriate place for general discussion. SO is more for specific questions.

https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt/13